# How can I replace Bfont with another font upon startup

Tags: text-object

Blender is being used by Openshot and by default Blender uses Bfont to create text objects.

Currently Bfont that my system has from the 2.79 lacks russian characters. So the only way to render russian text is to load a different font, which I can't do as Openshot uses Bfont in most of Blender interactions without my intervention uses blender -b.

So question is:
 how can I make sure that when blender is started it uses (as Bfont, default font to render text objects another font of my choice) and this is loaded upon startup.

I know how to do it by modifying source files and recompiling blender and openshot from scratch. 
I can put another font for blender as bfont and recompile. 
I can also edit python scripts on openshot side and try to use/load another font, prior to calling blender.

However, I wanted to achieve the same with vanilla blender (those that I download from blender website)

So any way to call as Bfont some other fine via  config option (User prefs) or placing a file in some ~/.blender/... directory?

Comment: I've never used Openshot. Is it bypassing your startup file?

Comment: Actually it is probably time the bfont as default for text objects was changed. Blender includes [other fonts](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/), which are used for the interface and support multiple languages. Until then, an addon could be made that replaces the current add text object and sets a better font.